# send the form value into the form action parameter

Tags: php, html

Can i send a input value into form action ?Let say, on the form the **phone number** taken.Now can i send the phone number as form action parameter "**number**"? Is their any way to send it?

```
<form method="post" action="abc.php?number=ph_number" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
   <input type="text" name="ph_number" value=""/>                   
   <input type="submit"  name="search"  value="SEND"/>
</form>
```

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance 
riad

Comment: Why do you need it to be sent as url parameter? you can use the GET method of HTTP to have all the form params in the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form method="GET" action="abc.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
   <input type="text" name="number" value=""/>                   
   <input type="submit"  name="search"  value="SEND"/>
</form>
```

Comment: hi,thx for your quick reply. sorry for late..because i test it many way...Can i do it using post method?because on the action parameter i have to include other some parameters.like:

<form method="POST" action="abc.php?text=somethoing&address=something&number=something" enctype="multipart/form-data">

thats why i need to use post method.Can i do it using post method??

Comment: Sure, if you modify your script to get the value from `$_POST`.

Comment: I have 2 parameters.1 of them is collected from script and one i should take from text box input.let see my example:
<form method="post" action="friend.php?title=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(@$msg_to_friend)?>&number=""?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

i can collect both data one using $_POST and another using $_GET mothod. But my problem is i have to send both data on the action parameter.so i can i do it???can u help pls..

Answer (score 3):

Change `action="abc.php?number=ph_number"` to `action="abc.php`

Change `name="ph_number"` to `name="number"`

When you click submit, the value contained in "number" text field will be passed to abc.php.

Receive the value with `$value = $_REQUEST['number'];` in abc.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave an empty action, and use the onSubmit event to load a javascript function that does whatever and redirects to the page according to the input value.

Html

```
<form .. action="" onsubmit="return abcByPhone(this);">
```

Javascript

```
function abcByPhone(form) {
   url = from.number.value;
   ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
I actually didn't read the question properly. I thought you wanted to redirect to different pages according to the input. Using plain GET (like the others mentioned) is fine for this.